# JQuery to dynamically assigning id to dynamically generated div, inside contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, attr

```
<div class="pad" id="test" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
    <div id="a0" class="lines" > text1</div>
</div>
```

I have a content editable div, and many child divs inside it which gets generated dynamically when user presses ENTER key (using jQuery ) to go to next line .An example of child div is the one above with  **id='a0'**.

**Aim:** To have a unique id be dynamically generated and assigned to these dynamically generated child divs.

**Below is the jQuery which I have used to to accomplish this task.**

```
function getSelectedNode()
```

This is thefunction which returns the **'id'** of line (i.e. child div) on which user is currently typing.

```
var lineCount=0;
```

**lineCount** variable has the value equal to total number of child divs generated.

```
 $(currentLine).next().attr('id','a'+(++lineCount));
```

Here `currentLine`contains  **id** of the line on which user is currently typing.On pressing ENTER key new div gets automatically generated after the current div and I try to  access using `.next()` and try to assign a new id to it using `.attr('id','a'+(++lineCount))`.

***Process of assign new id works well if I pass absolute value in the selector clause of jQuery i.e.:***

> $('#a0').next().attr('id','a'+(++lineCount));

instead of

> $(currentLine).next().attr('id','a'+(++lineCount));

```
var lineCount = 0;
var currentLine = "#a0";

function getSelectedNode() {
    if (document.selection) 
        return document.selection.createRange().parentElement();
    else {
        var selection = window.getSelection();

        if (selection.rangeCount > 0) 
          return selection.getRangeAt(0).startContainer.parentNode;
    }
}


$('.pad').keypress(function (event) {

    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

    if (keycode == '13') {
        var sn = getSelectedNode();
        currentLine = "#" + sn.getAttribute('id');

        $(currentLine).next().attr('id', 'a' + (++lineCount));
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the value of currentLine after you assign it?

Comment: as according to this line    'currentLine = "#" + sn.getAttribute('id');'    ,  currentLine's value will always be equal to 'id' of the line on which user is currently typing.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is single threaded, so you can use an int for this...

```
var indexer = 0;
function getUniqueId(){
   indexer++;
   return indexer.toString();
}
```

Caveat: I don't recommend declaring functions and properties at the document level in most web applications. Once you have this method tho, it's easy to implement...

```
$("<div id='myDiv" + getUniqueId() + "' />");
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but that is not what I want. I need to assign unique id to **already existing div** (the one that I described above ' $(currentLine).next() '   ) and **not to create a new div** with new id. This is because I am trying to make a texteditor in which every line has a unique id (and number of lines = number of lines user typed in contenteditable div)

Comment: If you can create a jsbin of an example of your code I could probably figure it out, but looking at the code, all I can think of is maybe currentLine isn't being set properly? Have you set a breakpoint there?

Comment: [http://jsbin.com/osugos/7/edit]( http://jsbin.com/osugos/7/edit)  It does not work as desired with mozilla firefox and internet explorer. **It works as desired only with google chrome with some minor errors which I hav described in jsbin link.**.